Water pipe bond in exterior disconnect
I've installed an emergency/service disconnect outside of my house. I'm bonding my grounds and neutrals in this enclosure. I have the following grounding and bonding conductors coming into the enclosure:

#4 Copper grounding conductor from my ground rods (I know a #6 would have been sufficient)
#4 Copper grounding conductor going to my sub-panel inside (used to be a main panel)
#4 Copper bonding conductor going to my water-pipe

As you can see in the pictures below, this QO Disconnect has two lugs directly next to the Neutral lugs, with a greens screw for bonding. It also came with two lugs that can be bolted to the enclosure with a screw in a pre-drilled hole.
I've connected the conductor from my ground rods and the one going to my sub-panel to the lugs next to the Neutral lug, and the water-pipe bonding conductor to the separate ground lugs.
Is it a problem that the only path between the water pipe bonding conductors and the ground-rods is through the sheet metal of the enclosure? Would it be better a small ground bar to the enclosure and using a jumper to the lugs next to the Neutral lugs?



